# Google Maps API, Can't get marker to show up at all

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have the map up and running but I'm unable to plant a marker at the lat and long specified both in 'center' and 'position'. Does anyone see the error? I had this working earlier but after adding the style array, it stopped, I must have accidentally messed something up but I'm not seeing it now.

```
<div id="map"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script>
    var map;
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 17,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(36, -110),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            styles: styleArray,
            scrollwheel: false,
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  mapOptions);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    var styleArray = [
        {
            featureType: "all",
            stylers: [ { saturation: -80 } ]
        },
        {
            featureType: "road.arterial",
            elementType: "geometry",
            stylers: [ { hue: "#00ffee" }, { saturation: 50 } ]
        },
        {
            featureType: "poi.business",
            elementType: "labels",
            stylers: [ { visibility: "off" } ]
        }
    ];

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: (36, -110),
        title:"Hello World!",
        map: (google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP),
    });

    marker.setMap(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are javascript errors in the posted code:

- `InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object`
- `InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map; and not an instance of StreetViewPanorama`

You have several issues with your code:

1. Your marker is instantiated outside the `initialize` function (so it is instantiated before the `map` variable is defined.  Move it inside the `initialize` function.
2. The `marker.setMap` function takes a `google.maps.Map` object as its argument, this is incorrect:

   ```
   marker.setMap(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);
   ```

should be:

```
marker.setMap(map);
```

3. This is incorrect, position needs to be a `google.maps.LatLng` object or a `google.maps.LatLngLiteral`, `(36, -110)` is neither, and the `map` property needs to be a `google.maps.LatLng`; this:

   ```
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: (36, -110),
     title:"Hello World!",
     map: (google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP),
   });
   ```

should be:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: google.maps.LatLng(36, -110),
    title:"Hello World!",
    map: map,
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/raohhace/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 17,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(36, -110),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    styles: styleArray,
    scrollwheel: false,
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
    mapOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(36, -110),
    title: "Hello World!",
    map: map,
  });

  marker.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

var styleArray = [{
  featureType: "all",
  stylers: [{
    saturation: -80
  }]
}, {
  featureType: "road.arterial",
  elementType: "geometry",
  stylers: [{
    hue: "#00ffee"
  }, {
    saturation: 50
  }]
}, {
  featureType: "poi.business",
  elementType: "labels",
  stylers: [{
    visibility: "off"
  }]
}];


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

4 Steps to make your marker appear.

- Put your key in the JS library. Like this:

  `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&key=[YOUR GOOGLE KEY]`

  Visit [this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) for detail.
- Put your code of creating marker into your initialize method, just make sure it is initialized after the map is created.
- The marker position should be an instance `new google.maps.LatLng(36, -110)` instead of your code `(36, -110)`
- `marker.setMap` method is unnecessary, we can remove it.

[image]